# Number of solutions modulo p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can anyone explain 1b? http://www.math.cmu.edu/~csmyth/21441/hw05solutions.pdf

I don't get how we get from $a^{p-1} \equiv 1$ to our conclusion

Comment: I believe the correct answer is "the equation will have up to $n$ solutions".  For instance, if $n=2$ with any odd prime $p$, then if there is a solution $q$ there is also solution $-q$.

Comment: Can I show that it has $n$ solutions? Or is it a false statement?

Comment: abiessu, If $n=2$ and $p$ is odd, that $(n,p-1)=2t\neq 1$.

Comment: Oops, I was wrong.  @Mr.Newman is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The Euler's Criterion say, that the equation $x^n\equiv a(\mathrm{mod\ } m)$, where $m=p^{\alpha}$ or $m=2p^{\alpha}$ is solvable for $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ iff
$$a^{\frac{\phi(m)}{(n,\phi(m))}}\equiv 1(\mathrm{mod\ }m).$$
The second statement of the criterion is true ($m=p$), since $\mathbf{a^{p-1}\equiv1(mod\  p)}$, and there exists a (non-zero in our case) solvation $x(\mathrm{mod\ }p)$. Since $(n,p-1)=1$, that there exists $s,u\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$ns=1+u(p-1).$$
So, with $\mathbf{x^{p-1}\equiv1(mod\  p)}$, we can write:
$$a^s\equiv x^{ns}\equiv x\cdot \left(x^{(p-1)}\right)^u \equiv x(\mathrm{mod\ }p)$$
and such $x$ is unique.